# Why child_added firebase show data on document ready?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I trying use realtime database but I get bug from my code. this is my code

```
<script>
 const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
var ref = firebase.database().ref().orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(1);

ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
   //show data
   console.log(snapshot.val())
});

</script>
```

from my code why data always show if i use `child_added` on document ready? I want to show data if I just added data to firebase.

please help me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) says:

> `child_added`: **This event is triggered once for each existing child** and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path.

So when you attach a `child_added` listener it immediately fires for each existing child that matches the query.

If you only want nodes that are added *after* you attach the listener, consider specifying the current time as a `startAt` condition:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(Date.now()).limitToLast(1);
```

---

The `limitToLast(1)` here may cause you to miss new child nodes if they are added in rapid succession or in batches. For example: somebody adds two new child nodes in one API call, your listener will only see the last one, which is probably not what you want. I recommend removing that limit.